# inserting value into database using post method not working

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

i want to update my database table **newlessontime** by posting a value from as3.but query is not working ...but when i give    *$etime = 4*  in php code   then database is updating *lesson1* **column** but but when it comes for post method, value is not inserting into lesson1 column why is this happening? **stdroll column value was inserted already** i want to update **lesson1** in same row of the table
 here is my php file

```
// lesson1t.php

include('connect.php');


$etime = $_POST['time1'];
//$etime = 4;

if (mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE newlessontime set lesson1=$etime WHERE stdroll=123")) {

    echo 'result=System Updated';

} else {
    echo 'result=error';
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

here is the fla file

```
home_Btn.buttonMode = true;
home_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, indexBtn_click1);

function indexBtn_click1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 myTime.stop();
 variables.time1 =  my_time.text ;
 var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/lesson1t.php');
 request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
 request.data = variables;
 var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(request);
 loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
 loader.load(request);
 loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataOnLoadl);
 function dataOnLoadl(event:Event) 
{
    var variables:URLVariables = URLVariables(event.target.data);
    trace(variables.result);    // gives : System Updated
}
 gotoAndPlay("manu");
 SoundMixer.stopAll();

}
```

Comment: When `indexBtn_click1` is run, what is the value of `my_time.text`?

Comment: it is timer time..i have set a timer to insert time into database..it is not fixed sometimes it is 0.20 or 0.15  _my_time.text_  is a dynamic text field

Comment: why update method is not working here is the code http://pastebin.com/i1gZK6En

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you problem is that you do not defined variable.time1 as a var in as3.

Try this...

```
home_Btn.buttonMode = true;
home_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, indexBtn_click1);

function indexBtn_click1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 myTime.stop();
 var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/lesson1t.php');
 request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
 //You should define what is variables...
 var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); //this you forgot!
 variables.time1 =  my_time.text ;
 request.data = variables;
 var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(request);
 loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
 loader.load(request);
 loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataOnLoadl);
 function dataOnLoadl(event:Event) 
 {
 var variables:URLVariables = URLVariables(event.target.data);
 trace(variables.result);    // gives : System Updated
  }
 gotoAndPlay("manu");
 SoundMixer.stopAll();

 }
```

Try this and tell us what happen...

Comment: no still showing error..but i have changed the query of **lesson1t.php** as **INSERT INTO newlessontime(lesson1) VALUES('$etime')** and tested..it works fine.and inserts into different row but i want to insert  time into the same row where stdroll is present.but when it comes for _UPDATE newlessontime set lesson1=$etime WHERE stdroll=123_  it doesn't work

Comment: i also tested it by changing lesson1 column type into **varchar** and **text**

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to give quote around `$etime`.
It should be `'$etime'` ..Now its working